# Odd subsetting behavior in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Could someone explain following. When I call

```
toy = data.frame(alpha = LETTERS, numeric = 1:26)
toy[2]
```

it returns the second column of the data frame. It's not broken or anything, but it goes against what I would expect from other subsetting operations in R. For instance, if you do the same thing with

```
toy2 = matrix(c(LETTERS, 1:26), nrow = 26)
toy2[2]
```

it returns "B".

Is there some deep reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

As I was typing this I realized what was going on.

The underlying datatype for a matrix is as vector, only one that "wraps" given how many rows/columns it has, which is stored in the `dim` attribute. `R` fills up the first column, then starts over in the next until the matrix is full. When you call `toy2[2]`, vector subsetting takes over and `R` looks for the second element of the underlying data structure, which is "B".

The underlying datatype for a data frame is a *list*. A data frame is a list of vectors and factors, each of which forms one of the columns of the data frame. When you call `toy[2]`, list subsetting takes over and `R` looks for the second element of the list underlying the data frame, which in this case is the `numeric` column. However, the returned value is *not* the contents of that element, but rather the list underlying the data frame subsetted to its second element. Calling `toy[[2]]` will return a numeric vector.